# Check if there a usb/AC connection

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app

I'm developing an universal windows phone application which checks if there a connection via usb or AC charging.
I used this code:

```
    var deviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Battery.GetDeviceSelector());
    var aggBattery = Battery.AggregateBattery;
    var report = aggBattery.GetReport();

    report.Status.ToString();
```

It works well for some devices.
There are few devices (devices which got upgraded from WP8 to WP10) that takes them 30 seconds to detect the "charging mode".

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: I want to know if there a way to detect a usb connection? or get the battery level?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there a way to detect a usb connection?

To detect USB device, we can use a [DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.aspx) object to detect when the device is added to or removed from the system.

For Windows 10 Universal app, here is a good sample: [Device enumeration sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/DeviceEnumeration)

> or get the battery level?

The Battery class does not provide method to get the battery level.

As a workaround, we can use [BatteryReport.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.power.batteryreport.remainingcapacityinmilliwatthours.aspx) to get the remaining power capacity of the battery, in milliwatt-hours. Also we can use [BatteryReport.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.power.batteryreport.fullchargecapacityinmilliwatthours.aspx) to get the fully-charged energy capacity of the battery. Then we can use BatteryReport.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours/BatteryReport.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours to get the battery level.

For example:

```cs
var deviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Battery.GetDeviceSelector());
var aggBattery = Battery.AggregateBattery;
var report = aggBattery.GetReport().RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours;
var report3 = aggBattery.GetReport().FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours;
MyText.Text = (report / (double)report3).ToString();
```

Comment: that's exactly what I do, but devices that upgraded to windows phone 10 (not pure WP10),detect the charging only after 30 seconds.